# Retrieving data from web site without api

Tags: java, http, httprequest, httpresponse

I need to query (using java) this site https://www.conversion-tool.com/bpmdetector/ in order to obtain bpm of a song previously uploaded. 
The site has no API ready to use, so I don't know how to retrieve the value I'm interested in.
Have you got any idea on how to proceed or any java libraries that can be useful for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at: https://jsoup.org/ It can parse an HTML page into a Java object which you can iterate/query over to get the value you want